# Yun availability

Tags: arduino-yun

I am starting a project that may need a lot of Arduino Yuns in the future, but today I found that they are not available on the official Arduino store.

What's the story on the Yun? Is it being replaced by something newer? Also, how can I evaluate the longer-term availability of this board?

In case it's helpful, I need the dual-processor setup, wifi capability, and extra storage of the Yun.

Comment: If you need a lot of them, the Yun, or frankly anything branded Arduino, is probably not the best choice.  For anything production oriented, define the specific characteristics you actually need, and then look at the range of platforms providing them.  There are lots of wifi/IoT type boards on the market, of both embedded linux and bare metal varieties.  You will be most secure if you can distinguish the generic parts of your system from the layers needed to tailor it to a particular board, as that gives you the future option of changing out the board based on market conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: Who knows?!

With all the in-fighting between the two Arduino factions (Arduino.cc and Arduino.org) it's anyone's guess what boards are going to be available this time next year, and of those that are available which of the two factions will be producing and distributing them.